# Learning perl, what does this line do?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my @file = grep { (/\.EW/i || /\.NS/i || /\.UD/i) }readdir(DIR);
```

Im trying to understand the regex as well as how grep and readdir relate to one another.

Comment: What's the result you get when using this line? I would suggest docs perlfunc, perlre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It, rather *verbosely*, filters all file names in a directory based on whether there is a sequence of a period followed by either `'EW'`, `'NS'`, or `'UD'` in the name of a file, without reference to case. ( `/i`: "ignore case" ).

It does the same thing as this:

```
my @files = grep { /\.(?:ew|ns|ud)/i } readdir(DIR);
```

However, it also would allow filenames where those sequences *aren't* the extensions, but the *beginning* of a *node* in the filename. These types of filenames are sometimes seen more in a *nix environment: (`file.ew.action.ext`). But note, I said *beginning* (ht to ikegami), so it matches `file.nst`, `file.nsx`, and so on. So if those are *extensions, it would be better to do the following:

```
/\.(?:ew|ns|ud)$/i
```

`$` indicating the end of the string (or before record separator).

Even if you wanted to keep the full range of behavior, and wanted all the extensions *starting* with those sequences, it is better to make it *explicit*, and write the expression like: `/\.(?:ew|ns|ud)\w*$/` (`\w*` meaning 0 or more "word characters" (letters, digits + underscore)).

Comment: ...and `\z` indicates end of string. Without `$` or `\z`, it would even match `.nslookuprc`

Comment: the cost of readdir is going to dwarf any time taken in the grep; this change is only worth even considering if you find this "optimization" more readable or easier to modify at need.

Comment: This is a lecture, not an answer. And your last paragraph is entirely wrong - there is no reason to require that the trailing characters in a file name are alphanumeric or underscore. The requirement is what it is, and we haven't been told that.

Comment: @Borodin, it contrasts the general *intention* of the code with the what can be guess is unintended behavior. One is the general interpretation of what somebody might be trying when writing code like that, the other is what it actually does. And word characters are a *reasonable* expectation for extensions. Not an absolute.

Answer (score 7):

readdir is returning an list of the files in DIR, where DIR is a handle to a directory.

The grep {} is applying that regexp to each value it sees, and anything matching is put in @files.

The regular expression itself is matching ".EW", ".NS" or ".US" within your filenames, in a case insensitive manner. (Quotes are mine for clarity).

Answer (score 2):

1. A directory was first `open`ed and it's handle is `DIR`
2. `readdir` generates a list of the opened directory's contents--both file and directory names
3. `grep` implicitly evaluates the expression in its code block against each list item  (held in Perl's default scalar `$_`). In this case a set of regexs  case-insensitively attempt to match '.EW', '.NS' or '.UD' in each list item.
4. If the expression in `grep`'s code evaluates to true, i.e., a match was found, the list item is passed to the array `@file`

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression explained:

```
/\.EW/i       the character '.' followed by the letters "EW" (case insensitive)
||            or
/\.NS/i       the character '.' followed by the letters "NS" (case insensitive)
||            or
/\.UD/i)      the character '.' followed by the letters "UD" (case insensitive)
```